# 15 year old crossing the Germany/Netherlands border - do I need parental letter?

Tags: germany, borders

I am 15 years old and travelling by train from Netherlands to Germany. Do I need a letter of consent from my parents or can I just buy a ticket and go? I will have my passport.

Comment: One of my sons used to live in Kleve, Germany and often went to the neighboring Nijmegen, Netherlands by bus. There were occasionally border checks on the bus: primarily the cops looking for weed. So  checks can happen and its definitely a good idea to bring your passport.

Comment: @deceze You are required to have some form of recognised ID to cross a Schengen border, even if there are no systematic checks. Not necessarily a passport, national ID cards are fine. No idea about the parental consent though. In France it used to be that a passport was automatic parental consent (when an ID card wasn't) but I have no idea if that's still the case, nor whether the same rule applied in other countries, and even less whether any parental consent is required.

Comment: @Hilmar, but most people just carry an ID card, I often leave my passport at home even when flying. These days it is common to suddenly realize one's passport is about to expire only when planing a trip to a different continent. It just lies on the bottom of the shelf.

Comment: In case you *or any future readers/searchers* are running away from an unsafe situation, +318002000 (call for free) https://veiligthuis.nl/

Comment: @jcaron the documents required to enter a Schengen country via an internal border are not specified in the Schengen Borders Code; they are left to national law.  In practice they don't tend to address the question specifically so many fall back on the documents required to enter via an external border, and in practice they don't check.  But some countries have fairly strict requirements about documents you must posses, without regard to border crossing, so ...

Comment: @deceze Germany requires basically everyone on German territory to have a passport (or a national ID card from an EU or Schengen country). The Netherlands has a similar but slightly less strictly worded requirement.  You won't get into trouble with these unless you are stopped by the police, but crossing an internal Schengen border is  a situation im which being stopped by police is fairly likely.  Trying to make this border crossing without a passport or national ID card is asking for trouble.

Comment: @phoog Yes, *an id*, not necessarily your _passport_. I've done that crossing by train several times (although that was admittedly quite a few years ago and I don't know if the mood has changed there in the meantime), and it's a… pretty unremarkable affair. You get on the train, you get off the train, end of story. I'm sure thousands of young people do it every day. Yes you _could_ get checked at any time and you better have _some_ id then; but that's about it _in my (perhaps outdated) experience_.

Comment: @deceze but not just any ID; it has to be a national ID that indicates citizenship of an EU or Schengen country, which is a document that most of the world's population does not have.  Of course most people crossing that border do have it, but we ought to be explicit lest a tourist from abroad thinks they can use their driver's license so they can leave the passport in the hotel safe.  I cross the border between France and Switzerland several times a month and have never been checked, but both countries have a more _laissez faire_ attitude to ID, I think even more so in the border region.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need any paperwork from your parents, but you are required (it is not just a good idea) to carry an official id card or a passport.

I am not sure about Dutch law, but you are required by German law to carry a recognized id card (e.g. an identiteitskaart if you are a Dutch citizen) or a passport. Customs checks or police looking for drugs are not uncommon at the Dutch/German border, also on public transport, and you will likely be fined by the German police if you do not carry an id or a passport.

Comment: @npst You are wrong. When crossing the German border (not in general), you are required to carry a recognized id.

Comment: The Netherlands is actually stricter than Germany, it's in fact required to *carry* ID there, even within the country and outside of any border crossing (making any special requirement related to border crossing kind of moot).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150029/discussion-on-answer-by-tor-einar-jarnbjo-15-year-old-crossing-the-germany-nethe); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 17):

Too long, didn't read: ID is strictly required, letter is recommended.

---

There are no formal border controls at the internal borders of the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area), to which both the Netherlands and Germany belong. Chances are you won't meet an official at all.

But in order to control illegal immigration there are more customs and immigration officers around, sometimes quite far from the actual border, who are looking for suspicious activities. If you are not Caucasian, if it is obvious that you are a minor, if you look as if you might smuggle dope from the Netherlands to Germany (bad idea!) or attract their attention in any other way, they may stop and question you. In fact, it is their job to look out for minors because it is not uncommon that a separated and alienated parent tries to take the child away from the other parent. Society in general thinks that 15 year olds need special protection ;-).

There is a [website from the German government](https://verwaltung.bund.de/leistungsverzeichnis/en/rechte-und-pflichten/102711702) detailing the regulations. It contains a link to [REGULATION (EU) 2016/399 OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0399). That regulation says about minors in Annex VII,
*Special rules for certain categories of persons* (all emphasis in the following quotes by me):

> 6.3. In the case of minors travelling unaccompanied, border guards shall ensure, by means of **thorough checks on travel documents and supporting documents,** that the minors do not leave the territory against the wishes of the person(s) having parental care over them.

The German document then lists the requirements for border crossings.

- The hard requirement, not only for minors, is that EU citizens traveling
  within the EU need a **passport or ID card.**
- For minors, they say:

  > To facilitate travel, minors travelling alone and entering or leaving Germany - although not required by law - ***should* carry a declaration of consent signed by the persons with legal custody of the child,** in addition to their own valid travel document (passport, children's passport or identity card). Where possible, such declaration should be issued in the languages of the home country and of the country of destination.
  > It should specify:
  >
  > - that the minor may travel alone
  > - the contact details of the parents with custody
  > - the route being travelled
  > - the contact details of the accompanying adult(s), if applicable

There is some additional talk about power of attorney documents which I think is a bit overkill, given that you'll likely need no documents whatsoever. The advice to carry copies of your ID card or passport is good though in general. These days, you'd simply take pictures of the relevant pages with your phone (and keep the phone separate).

Answer (score 5):

You did not directly ask for it, but both on the way **out** of Germany and the way in you should have a written consent from *all* your legal guardians. So the best idea is to have it mention the whole trip.

[Here](https://verwaltung.bund.de/leistungsverzeichnis/en/rechte-und-pflichten/102711702) the content of the letter is described, and also that it *should* be carried rather than *must* be carried. The lack of such a letter is no immigration offense, but there may be questions of a minor absconding or one parent taking a child away from joint custody. The letter with contact details can minimize delays from suspicious police officers.

Comment: Does Germany too issue ID cards ["not valid for travel abroad"](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/E-7-2012-010654_EN.html) where parents fail to provide both consent to travel abroad to their child?

Comment: The page you link to advises having such a letter both on entering _and_ on leaving Germany, though neither is required by law.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ Germany does issue id cards not valid for travel abroad, but in other situations and not because parents do not consent to children travelling alone.

Comment: I don't know. My now 17 year old child has been leaving/entering Germany by herself on occasion since she was 12 (yes, 12) and no one ever has asked her for a letter (or tried to verify with her parents what she was doing). And she has to go through passport control at an airport, so she's checked every single time.

Comment: @Marianne013 There may be more controls these days than in the past because of illegal immigration. Even if we presume that the OP is Caucasian ("white") and otherwise inconspicuous, there is a chance that she'll attract the attention of one of the officers.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, the scenario the police would worry about is one guardian abducting the child from the other guardian. That is more worrisome for *German* police when one is leaving Germany, while on entering the worrisome thing would be immigration status.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ See: [Prado: DEU-BP-12001](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/DEU-BP-12001/index.html): *On 1 July 2015, Germany introduced a new law .... One of the aims of the new provisions is to prevent the unauthorised travel of so-called foreign fighters out of Germany by revoking not only the passports but also the identity cards of such citizens. Instead, and in order to enable such individuals to continue to identify themselves, they are provided with a 'Substitute Identity Card' which does not permit the holder to leave Germany.*

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica What past ? This has all happened in the last 5 years (she's still a minor) - even in the Covid years all immigration was interested in was the Covid paperwork (and FRA airport was very pedantic in that regard) and not any letters from any parents. They always ask her where she's travelling to, but they never tried to verify anything.

Comment: @Marianne013, when I was a child, my experiences were similar to yours. But then I and the people I traveled with would have met 'positive' criteria of racial profiling -- ethnic Germans, able to articulate what they were doing, etc. Think of the letter as insurance. A child may not need it, but if it is required, the hassle of not having it outweighs the effort of writing it.

Comment: @o.m. How is 'being able to articulate what you are doing' a criterion of racial profiling?

Comment: @user140937 I believe what o.m. is referring to is how an ethnic German is less likely to be hassled by the police and less likely to be formally asked about identity. This likelihood is increased if the person can communicate clearly and seems to the officer to be behaving "normally."  I infer this because "positive" is in quotation marks -- it improves the officer's assessment of the person being racially profiled rather than making it worse.  That doesn't mean that the profiling itself is positive.

Comment: Language skills are not necessarily a component of race, but of course "racial" profiling isn't always about race, either; it's more about identifying someone as not belonging based on criteria that may have some statistical correlation but are not dispositive.  Race is a prominent criterion and perhaps the most common, but it is not the only one.  Dress and other indications of socioeconomic status can come into play, as well as language skills, accent, dialect, etc.

Comment: @phoog, with racial profiling I mean not just race but also presumed class and wealth, based on appearance. It is an unfortunate fact that some people are more likely than others to be subjected to "random" checks by law enforcement, and looking the "right" way and giving the "right" answers is part of this. The officers would rationalize this as the person responding "normally," based on their notion of normal ...

Comment: @o.m. The question only implies it, but assuming that the asker (and her passport) is indeed Dutch and travelling alone, why would abduction by guardian be more worrisome to border control on leaving than on entering? The risk of abduction is significantly lower if there is no one with her to begin with, but even if it really was an abduction scenario, it would be more likely to be from the Netherlands to Germany (residence matching passport) than vice versa.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I'm quoting the *German* authorities. They are generally not worried about outgoing people, with a few exceptions.

Comment: @o.m. My question was why you only advised having the letter when leaving, not when entering, but I just now noticed you edited the answer to include both, so that question is now moot.